# What's the difference between print and type ? Python

Tags: python-3.x, function

Hi I am new to coding and try to learn Python by myself. I wonder what's the difference between both of those functions ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

**type()** returns the type of variable that you are using. 
**print()** outputs the value passed in the parameters of function

Example:
a=1
type(a) will print "Int"
print(a) will print "1"

Comment: if the answer is correct, do accept it so that it can help others as well. Good Luck with python and keep learning :)